# How to install Django app without its models?

Tags: django

There's a third party Django application that I want to add to `INSTALLED_APPS`, but I'm not going to use its models and I would prefer to not have them polluting my database. How to achieve that?

Comment: How do you know that the 3rd party app would work without their models?

Comment: I need a form widget from the app, which has no dependency on the models. I've looked at the code. But the widget has a template and statics, which are not found unless I have the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @Rubinous Did my answer fix your issue?

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey I ended up writing my own widget, so I didn't try it out, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I would recommend doing this, but if you want to you can override the migrations using the [`MIGRATIONS_MODULES`  setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES):

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'app_name': None,
}
```

This will disable migrations for that application. But like Shang Wang said, if you do this and the app requires those models then the app won't work.