# How to dynamically make an existing non-abstract django model, abstract?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I think I have a more or less unorthodox and hackish question for you. What I currently have is django project with multiple apps.
I want to use a `non-abstract model (ModelA)` of one app (`app1`) and use it in another app (`app2`) by subclassing it. App1's models
should not be migrated to the DB, I just want to use the capabilities of app1 and it's model classes, by extending its functionality and logic.
I achieved that by adding both apps to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, and preventing app1's models being migrated to the DB.

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'App1',
    'App2',
)

# This is needed to just use App1's models
# without creating it's database tables
# See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35921487/1230358
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'App1': None,
}
```

So far so good, ugly and hackish, I know... The remaining problem is now that most of app1's models are non-abstract (ModelA) and if I try
to subclass them, none of the ModelA's fields get populated to the db into the table named `app2_modelb`. This is clear to me, because I excluded the App1 from
migrating to the DB and therefore the table app1_modela is completely missing in the DB.

My idea now was to clone ModelA, preserve all its functionallity, and changing it's Meta information from non-abstract to abstract (`ModelB.Meta.abstract = True`).
I hope that by this, all the original fields of ModelA will be inherited to ModelB and can be found in its respective DB table and columns (`app1_modelb`).

What I have right now is:

```
# In app1 -> models.py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255)
    subtitle =  models.CharField(_('subtitle'), max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = False # just explicitly for demonstration


# In app2 -> models.py
from app1.models import ModelA

class ModelB(ModelA):
    pass
    # Just extending ModelAdoes not create the fields title and subtitle fields in app2_modelb
    # because ModelA.meta.abstract = False
```

My current way (pseudo code) to make an existing non-abstract model abstract looks like this:

```
# In app2 -> models.py
from app1.models import ModelA

def get_abstract_class(cls):
    o = dict(cls.__dict__)
    o['_meta'].abstract = True
    o['_meta'].app_label = 'app2'
    o['__module__'] = 'app2.models'

    #return type('Abstract{}'.format(cls.__name__), cls.__bases__, o)
    return type('Abstract{}'.format(cls.__name__), (cls,), o)

ModelB = get_abstract_class(ModelA)

class ModelC(ModelB):
    # title and subtitle are inherited from ModelA
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=255)
```

This does not work, and after this lengthy description my (simple) question would be, if and how is it possible to clone a non-abstract model class preserving all its functionality and how to change it to be abstract?

**Just to be clear. All upper fuzz is about, that I can't change any code in app1. May it be that app1 is a django app installed via pip.**

Comment: Is your intention to disallow someone from making an instance of ModelA? Since you're going down the hacky route anyway you could always raise an error in the models save method if it is a ModelA class calling it...

Comment: Will you add any new fields?

Comment: The intention is the following. Let's say I want to reuse some models of a django-blog application (app1 and ModelA) that I find very useful for my belongings (app2). Sadly app1.model.ModelA is not abstract, because in the django-blog application, it does not need to be abstract, because inside app1 it is a - final - model class. If I want to use it in my app (app2), it has to be abstract so that I can subclass it and that all fields (also the ones of ModelA) are generated in the table (app2_modelb). All in all it's about reusing non-abstract models that are originally not intended for reuse.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, no field changes. Model should stay the same but be abstract.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, sorry for the misunderstanding! I have to add fields to the child class. Should be like ModelC in the last upper code block.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, in app1

```
AbstractBaseModelA(models.Model):
    # other stuff here
    class Meta:
        is_abstract=True


ModelA(AbstractBaseModelA):
    # stuff
```

in app2:

```
MobelB(AbstractBaseModelA):
    # stuff
```

Sorry if I've misunderstood your aims, but I think the above should achieve the same end result.

Comment: Or is it important that `issubclass(ModelB, ModelA)`?

Comment: I can't change any code in app1, think of it that app1 is a django app installed via pip. Sorry that I left this unclear!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is philosophy or programming, but if the latter: it's open source so you *can* change it. There's probably a git or similar source repository from which you can fork and create a patch.The other question is whether that is wise. For a change such as this, which is unlikely to break app1, it may be acceptable. Better still if you can convince the "upstream" developers that the model ought to be abstract because what you find useful, many others may likewise. In which case they may incorporate your idea  in their next release.

Comment: True words @nigel. Normally I don't like that hackish ways but I was curious if i miss a simple trick that might make that possible.